# Exception calling ExecuteWithResults error in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0, execute

I have two table in my database called "LitHold" and I have a PowerShell Script that put a user litigation hold.Everything were running fine lastweek but some reason I'm getting this error now and the activity is not inserting it into my sql Database anymore.

```
#My database Connection

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
#Need SmoExtended for backup
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
$s = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server "My Server Instance"
$db = $s.Databases.Item("LitHold")


#This is how I pass event Id and column value through out the script.
$EventId = Get-EventId 1
Set-UsrHistory $EventId.Event_Id $gein $geid



#Get ID from Event Table
Function Get-EventId($EventId) {
    $query = "select Event_Id from List_of_Events where Event_Id = $EventId"
    $result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)

    # Show output
    return $result.Tables[0]
}

#Insert it in to User History table with Event Id and Event Name from Event Table
Function Set-UsrHistory($EvtId, $GEIN, $GEID, $UPN, $OneDrive, $Mailbox) {
    #2022-02-01 08:15:56.000
    $query = "select top 1 * from User_History where Event_Id = $EvtId and GEIN = $GEIN and GEID = '$GEID' and UPN = '$UPN' order by Id desc"
    $query
    $result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)
    $DatCnt = $result.Tables[0].Rows.Count
    If ($DatCnt -eq 0) {
        #Insert everything at the begining
        $CreatedDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
        $query = "insert into User_History (Event_Id,GEIN,GEID,UPN,OneDrive, Mailbox,CreatedDate,) VALUES ('$EvtId',$GEIN,'$GEID','$UPN','$OneDrive', '$Mailbox','$CreatedDate')"
        $result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)
    }
```

This is the error that I'm getting and I don't think it's anything todo with line:726

```
write-log : Exception calling "ExecuteWithResults" with "1" argument(s): "Execute with results failed for Database 'LitHold'. "
At line:726 char:6
+         write-log $ErrorMessage -level Error
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Write-Log
```

because if I don't call my function and remove this line of code

```
Set-UsrHistory $EventId.Event_Id $gein $geid
```

then it's running without any errors. It was running fine lastweek but not sure why it giving that error now.

```
        Catch {
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            $errType = $error[0].exception.gettype().fullname
            write-log "ERROR TYPE: $errType"
            write-log $ErrorMessage -level Error
        }


function Write-Log 
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    Param 
    ( 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)] 
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] 
        [Alias("LogContent")] 
        [string]$Message, 
 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
        [Alias('LogPath')] 
        #[string]$Path='.\ScriptLog.log', 
        [string]$Path=$Global:LogFile,
         
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
        [ValidateSet("Error","Warn","Info")] 
        [string]$Level="Info", 
         
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
        [switch]$NoClobber 
    ) 
 
    Begin 
    { 
        # Set VerbosePreference to Continue so that verbose messages are displayed. 
        $VerbosePreference = 'Continue' 
    } 
    Process 
    { 
         
        # If the file already exists and NoClobber was specified, do not write to the log. 
        if ((Test-Path $Path) -AND $NoClobber) { 
            Write-Error "Log file $Path already exists, and you specified NoClobber. Either delete the file or specify a different name." 
            Return 
            } 
 
        # If attempting to write to a log file in a folder/path that doesn't exist create the file including the path. 
        elseif (!(Test-Path $Path)) { 
            Write-Verbose "Creating $Path." 
            $NewLogFile = New-Item $Path -Force -ItemType File 
            } 
 
        else { 
            # Nothing to see here yet. 
            } 
 
        # Format Date for our Log File 
        $FormattedDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
 
        # Write message to error, warning, or verbose pipeline and specify $LevelText 
        switch ($Level) { 
            'Error' { 
                Write-Error $Message 
                $LevelText = 'ERROR:' 
                } 
            'Warn' { 
                Write-Warning $Message 
                $LevelText = 'WARNING:' 
                } 
            'Info' { 
                Write-Verbose $Message 
                $LevelText = 'INFO:' 
                } 
            } 
         
        # Write log entry to $Path 
        "$FormattedDate $LevelText $Message" | Out-File -FilePath $Path -Append 
    } 
    End 
    { 
    } 
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Without knowing what `Write-Log` is doing we cannot do much here. Is that another function you wrote? Something you found online?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Hi I just uploaded the Write-Log. it's basically in the Catch blog. please take a look. thanks

Comment: Which line does the error message correspond to? It looks like it's failing either at the select or, my guess, insert SQL executions. Then it throws you out and into the catch statement, where the `Write-Log` outputs the error. I would check the SQL statement being run, and see if permissions may have been changed to not allow write access.

Comment: I'm with HAL9256, you need to figure out which line that error refers to. I'd comment out the second `$result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query)` line, and try it. If it doesn't throw an error then there's a write issue and you need to investigate your rights. Maybe last week you ran PowerShell as admin and this week you didn't?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to `Write-Verbose $query` before each call to `ExecuteWithResults` either. I'd be suspecting SQL Injection problems here, where the values you're injecting into the query contain some character/s making the query invalid, which is something that makes `ExecuteWithResults` a non-starter for anything serious.

Comment: Consider instead using Parameterized Queries via the more normal [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection) and [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand) route, adding an [SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter) to the command for each parameter in your query string.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Hi.. I just check and if I commented out the first $result = $db.ExecuteWithResults($query) then it's running without any error?. any idea what might be the reason?

Comment: if you comment out the first query it stops everything since the rest is dependent on the first query getting results. Do you still get no errors if you uncomment the first query, and then comment out the second one?